# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a `Next.js` app

This is one of my page/component looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { SomeLocalStorageComponent } from "some-external-lib";

const MyComponent = () => {
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
{
    if (isBrowser) {
        <SomeLocalStorageComponent></SomeLocalStorageComponent>
    }
 }

};

export default MyComponent;
```

This is throwing the below run time error

> Server Error 
> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Here `SomeLocalStorageComponent` is an external library component which is dependant on a `localStorage` variable

When this `SomeLocalStorageComponent` is used in a React app, it functions as expected however when I'm consuming this into Next.js app it throws the error.

how to get rid of this error?

Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next/dynamic`:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const SomeLocalStorageComponent = dynamic(() => import('some-external-lib'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

It will disable ssr for imported component

If your external library exports multiple components you can do something like this:

```
const SomeLocalStorageComponent = dynamic(
    async () => (await import('some-external-lib').SomeExportedComponent,
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
)
```

You should do above for each component you want to disable ssr

And if you want to have ssr in imported component you can import it normally:

```
import { TestComponent } from "some-external-lib"
```

Also protip:

You can export component with no ssr to a new file:

```
//TestComponentNoSsr.js

const TestComponent = dynamic(
    async () => (await import('some-external-lib').TestComponent,
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
)

export default TestComponent
```

Comment: Thanks! it makes sense & gave it a try with it earlier. But the problem is that the `external-lib` has multiple components so how do I mention which component to load. Please suggest

Comment: editted my answer :)

Comment: Thank you. One more query, so in case I need to import `2 (or n)` components from this `external-lib`, I need to have that many times `dynamic()`

Comment: Yes, I think so